# How to pass error validation for format number in textfield using yii?

Tags: yii

i use extension moneymasking in textfield but i get validation error when save data , the error like this  "jum Byr Pokok must be a number" , the value in textfiels was 5.000.000, ho to save data and pass the validation with format number money in text field ?

Tks & regards,

Comment: show the code you are working on and did you try entering the value without decimal like **5000000** ??

Answer (score 0):

Could be very simple just add a Regular expression

just like this in model file

```
public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
    array('your_price_field', 'match','pattern'=>'/^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,4})?$/', 'message'=>'{attribute} can only contain Price.'),
);
    }
```

Comment: i have try this but still error "Jum Byr Pokok must be a number." :(